# Base values on drop down box

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code set for rows to Auto Archive to another tab. I currently have it set based on a true/false. I would like it to be based on Drop Down box.

Below is my code I currently have.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 11 or K
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "ACTIVITY REPORT" && r.getColumn() == 11 && r.getValue() == true) 
 {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Activity Archive");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the drop-down box? What are the possible values?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance  the drop down box(via data validation) is on column K. The values are all of these. HIRED INTERN-SP,HIRED SDR-SP,HIRED,HIRED Intern,HIRED SDR,NP LDR,NP CND A AR,NP CND A OFFER,NO SHOW,NP ORL,NP CND A Zoom Int.,NP CND A 1 FL,NP BACKGROUND,NP CND A ACCEPTED

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "ACTIVITY REPORT" && e.range.columnStart == 11 && e.value) {
    const tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("e.value");
    const trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```